# Where is Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Enabler.config in Sitecore 9.1?

Tags: federated-authentication

We can find Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Enabler.config configuration file in `App_Config\Include\Examples` folder to enable Federated authentication in Sitecore version 8.2. We just need to remove .example from the end of the file.

But when i tried to find out this configuration file in Sitecore 9.1, i was not able to find out this file.

I know that Sitecore 9.1 introduced Sitecore Identity (SI) to provides a separate identity provider, and allows user to set up SSO (Single Sign-On) across Sitecore services and applications.

Sitecore also mentioned that it does not support the Active Directory integration, and for that we should use federated authentication instead.

Now the question is, how to use or enable federated authentication  if we don't find Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Enabler.config file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sitecore 9.1.0 and later enabled the Federated authentication entries by default that's why we are seeing the .\Website\App_Config\Include\Examples\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.Disabler.config.example but not the enabler file. You can find the federated authentication related entries in the below file, just validate whether the federated is enabled or not.

**\Website\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin.Authentication\Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config**

For ex - Added the sample where they set the Federated Authentication as "True"

```
<configuration>
...
   <settings>
      <setting name="Owin.Authentication.Enabled" value="true" security:require="Sitecore" />

      <!--  FEDERATED AUTHENTICATION ENABLED
            Determines if federated authentication is enabled. Sitecore federated authentication is based on OWIN authentication,
            To enable federated authentication, you must enable "Owin.Authentication.Enabled".

            Default value: true -->
      <setting name="FederatedAuthentication.Enabled" value="true" security:require="Sitecore" />
...
   </settings>
...
</configuration>
```

So ignore the existing settings and just configure your new third party provider, map claims and write your own custom provider for owin.identityProviders etc. Basically execute the steps which are not part of initial setup.

Comment: I was looking for these settings in \Website\App_Config\Sitecore\Owin\Sitecore.Owin.config but i didn't find it in <settings> section.

Comment: @ArvindGehlot have a look at Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config.. Updated the answer as well.